# unable to display glossary

Tags: glossaries

I would like to have a simple glossary in a specific point of my text.
I used this at the beginning

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{edge}
{
    name=edge,
    description={vertex}
}
```

and the `\printglossary` in the point where i prefer the glossary to appear.I'm getting no error but still nothing appears.

Comment: Do you run Makeglossaries from the Toolchain?

Comment: Is there a `\gls{edge}` command or `\glsaddall` in your document? Please post a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: No there isn't a \gls{edge} command or \glsaddall. Should there be one?

Comment: @Naphaneal I'm not sure what you mean by Toolchain.I'm sorry I'm a bit new at tex.

Comment: @Jac: Yes, it should ;-) `glossaries` does only print referenced entries, i.e. the ones explicitly stated with `\gls{edge}` (since edge is your entry name) or automatically add all with `\glsaddall`.

Comment: @Jac: I'm afraid you need to provide information about your LaTeX setup before I can answer that properly. If you use MiKTeX and TeXstudio you need to run Makeglossaries from the Tool->Commands->Makeglossaries
or call makeglossaries from the shell.

Comment: @Naphaneal: Not everybody uses those `editors` that pretend to simplify the 'ToolChain' ;-)

Comment: @Jac: I am using MikTex

Answer (score 1):

This works out of the box, if the perl script `makeglossaries` is called after compilation and then two additional compilations are used. Or use `\makenoidxglossaries`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries % or \makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{edge}
{
    name=edge,
    description={vertex}
}

\newglossaryentry{other}
{
    name=other,
    description={Fake entry}
}


\begin{document}

\gls{edge}

\printglossaries %or \printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```